# Update selected rows on datasheet form (subform)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Scenario:  datasheet form as subform with a command button on the main form to update selected records' status field with the status of "ready".

Comment: I don't see any question here. What is the problem you're having *exactly*?

Comment: Apologies...  I need to be able to select records in a datasheet subform and then click on a command button that will update those specific records' status field with the word "ready".   I have instructions on how to enumerate selected records via a command button, but am not sure how to update the status field from that point

Answer (score 2):

Loop the *RecordsetClone* of the subform:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me!NameOfSubformControlOnMainForm.Form.RecordsetClone

While Not rs.EOF
    If <record is member of the selected records ...> Then
        rs.Edit
            rs!Status.Value = "Ready"
        rs.Update
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
```